# is there a way for typescript to judge empty value

Tags: typescript

Is there a way typescript check empty value, for example:

```
type int64 = Exclude<string, ''>//type of string except empty string

let obj:{[prop:string]:int64} = {
    test : '11'
}
obj.test = ''
```

When I assign an empty string to property, can typescript throw an error or transform to no empty value?

Comment: you can do this type int64 = Exclude<string |  any>. This will work for you.

Comment: Exclude only works on unions, which `string` isn't.